# Compare univariate ARIMA and LSTM predictions

Tags: neural-networks, arima, lstm

I am trying to learn how to make predictions for a univariate time series using an LSTM neural network. I know how to work with time series using traditional ARIMA models but with the LSTM I am getting confused. Below I have an example.

As an example, consider that I have a univariate dataset with 1000 data points and that I want to predict the next 12 points. It is monthly data.

**ARIMA**

What I would do was to split the 1000 data points into two sets, one of 988 data points and another one of 12 points. So I would fit the model in 988 data points and make a 12 data points prediction. After, I would compare the prediction with the other 12 data points I previously split

For an ARIMA model, I would use a package such as [auto.arima](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.17.0/topics/auto.arima) in R and make a code like that:

```
my_data # Initial data with 1000 data points
train_data = my_data[1: 988] #first 988 data points 
test_data = my_data[989: 1000] #last 12 data points

y = ts(my_data, freq = 12, start=c(1913,1)) #start date of the training series

yt = window(y, end = c(1995,04)) #end date of the training series

yfit = auto.arima(yt) #fit the model 
yfor = forecast(yfit, h = 12) #predict the next 12 data points

rmse(test_data, yfor$mean) #Calculate the RMSE of the predictions vs test data
```

**LSTM**

For the case of LSTM, I need to put scale the data and put it in the sliding window format, with 12 data points and input and 12 as output.

After I fit the model in the training data set, I predict the data in the test dataset and compare the predicted results with the hold-out dataset. Is it the right way to do it?

```
my_data # Initial data with 1000 data points
train_data = my_data[1: 976] #first 976 data points
test_data = my_data[977: 988] #test dataset with 12 data points
holdout_data = my_data[989: 1000] #last 12 data points for comparing
```

Is it not possible to simply fit the model and make a prediction like what was done in the ARIMA case?

If I want to compare my ARIMA with my LSTM I will have problems because I fitted the models in different datasets

Comment: Is what not possible? In general yes, you should apply the same procedure to both models.

Comment: To fit/predict the model as I did in ARIMA, taking the same size of the training dataset and make a prediction. 

As far as I understood, in the LSTM I would need to take a smaller training dataset and after make the predictions in the test dataset. And finally, compare these predictions with a portion of the dataset that I hold.